# Showing point values by default on ZedGraph

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, zedgraph

I'm building and displaying a ZedGraph in a WinForm. When I rightclick on the graph, there is an option for "show point values". When that's enabled, hovering over a point will give the X/Y values for that point.

1. Is there a way to have this enabled by default.
2. My X-Axis is an XDate. I know how to set the scale format on the X-Axis, but how can I set the format in the tooltip?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When your form is initialized, do something like:

```
var zgc = msGraphControl1.zedGraphControl1;

zgc.IsShowPointValues = true;
zgc.PointValueFormat = "0.000";
zgc.PointDateFormat = "d";
```

That should do it.